# VNC into my workspace on cloud9

Tags: vnc, cloud9-ide

I'm going to code in a group a Python programm with tkinter, and I would like to do it online with cloud9.
But in this case, I will need an X environment to run and test it.
I thought about launching a vncserver on the workspace, which is already possible with tools preinstalled like vncserver or x11vnc.
But it seems that [project]-[pseudo].c9.io:5901 is not accessible, and that only port 80 and 443 are available to serve.
Can I use port 80 or 443 for an instance of vncserver ? If yes, how can I do it ?
I would like also to be able to connect with a tool like novnc in the browser. Do I need to serve it from the workspace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah go to https://github.com/fjakobs/cloud9-vnc and download the zip file. Extract it to your Hard Drive and upload the files to your Workspace (File/Upload Local Files). Then run install.sh and when it's done, run run.sh to actually start the VNC Server. It will give you a link to the NoVNC Page from where you can connect to your Workspace. And there you have it, a basic fluxbox desktop with terminal. (Right Click then you can access all the Programs.)

Comment: Yes absolutely! This is what I've done for my project a year ago and this is what I recommend to users on Cloud9 (for example, check this: https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-set-display-in-my-workspace/1646/8?u=etiennewan :)

Comment: Unfortunately the url  https://github.com/fjakobs/cloud9-vnc no longer works. But there is another project https://github.com/shadowcodex/c9.ide.desktop

Comment: I kept a copy of the repository, I reuploaded it some days ago: https://github.com/etiennewan/cloud9-vnc